# Overriding an Autowired Bean in Unit Tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Is there a simple way I can easily override an autowired bean in specific unit tests? There is only a single bean of every type in the compile classes so it's not a problem for autowiring in this case. The test classes would contain additional mocks. When running a unit test I'd simply like to specify an additional Configuration that says basically, while running this unit test use this mock instead of the standard bean.

Profiles seem a bit overkill for what I require and I'm not sure this would be achievable with the Primary annotation as different unit test could have different mocks.

Comment: Have you tried @ContexConfiguration? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig

Would you like to have different mocks for different test classes or different mocks for different test methods in the same test class?

Comment: Yes, this is what I envisioned, setting my standard configuration along with the test configuration with the beans to override in the test configuration. Different mocks for a whole class would be sufficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding beans in Integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742920/overriding-beans-in-integration-tests)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you just simply want to provide a different bean in your tests, i think you don't need to use spring profiles or mockito.

Just do the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class })
public class MyTest
{
    @Configuration
    @Import(Application.class) // the actual configuration
    public static class TestConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public IMyService myService()
        {
            return new MockedMyService();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

NOTE: tested with spring boot 1.3.2 / spring 4.2.4

Comment: I got "a definition for bean ... already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override." I had to change the "myService()" method to some other name e.g. "myServiceMock()". I would also recommend to use @Primary annotation (for IMyService) to make sure that the bean defined in TestConfig configuration will override the one from Application configuration.

Comment: @Kacper86 it's because you're using Spring 4.1 or below, that bug was fixed in 4.2

Comment: What is the `@Import` annotation for?  Is that only needed if you want to use existing beans in your test config?

Comment: Why the class needs to be static?

Comment: @Kacper86: Adding "Primary" annotation resolved Spring's complaints about having found 2 implementations for the interface. Thank you!

Comment: I also had to use a `@Primary` annotation to override the original bean (spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.4.RELEASE); thx @Kacper86

Comment: This solution is working perfectly on spring-boot-starter-parent:2.5.5. No need to use `@Primary`. I just kept the TestConfig as a solo class so I can import and all other tests too.

Answer (score 52):

In Spring Boot 1.4 there's a simple way for doing that:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyApplication.class })
public class MyTests {
    @MockBean
    private MyBeanClass myTestBean;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
         ...
         when(myTestBean.doSomething()).thenReturn(someResult);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
         // MyBeanClass bean is replaced with myTestBean in the ApplicationContext here
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MyApplication`?

Comment: You should replace that with the name of your mail application class that contains main() function and is annotated with @SpringBootApplixation

Comment: If you want to replace the bean with a Mockito mock, this is the best answer.  Otherwise (e.g. if you want to inject a custom object) it doesn't help.

Comment: To make `@MockBean` works you need `@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)`. Some other annotation or configuration can magically do it for you. Check the docs ))

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem and I solved with a mix and I find this one more useful and reusable. I created a spring profile for the tests and a config class that overrides the beans I want to mock in a very simple way:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@Import(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ConfigurationTests {

    @MockBean
    private Producer kafkaProducer;

    @MockBean
    private SlackNotifier slackNotifier;

}
```

By doing that I can @Autowire those mock beans and use mockito to verify on them. Main advantage is that now all tests seamlessly get the mock beans without any per-test change. 
Tested with:

> spring boot 1.4.2

Answer (score 6):

Since Spring Boot 1.4.0 instead of explicitly specifying `@Configuration` for tests, simply add static nested class annotated with `@TestConfiguration` and provide your replacement `@Bean` annotated with `@Primary`.

`@TestConfiguration` will be added to your primary Spring Boot test context (which means your production bean will still be created), but the one from `@TestConfiguration` will be used, because of the `@Primary`.

Comment: This works, with a few notes:

The test config class needs to be imported on the test, even if it's a static inner class, eg. `@Import(MyTest.TestConfig.class)`. 


The factory method needs to be named differently from the one in the production config (eg.`@Configuration @Bean thing(); @TestConfiguration @Primary @Bean thingMock();`)

Answer (score 3):

You should use spring profiles in order to know what kind of bean you want to use in different contexts.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score -1):

As mats.nowak commented, `@ContextConfiguration` is useful for this.

Say a parent test class is like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/some-dao-stuff.xml"
    ,"classpath:spring/some-rest-stuff.xml"
    ,"classpath:spring/some-common-stuff.xml"
    ,"classpath:spring/some-aop-stuff.xml"
    ,"classpath:spring/some-logging-stuff.xml"
    ,"classpath:spring/some-services-etc.xml"
})
public class MyCompaniesBigTestSpringConfig {
...
```

Create a child test class:

```
package x.y.z;
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyOneOffTest extends MyCompaniesBigTestSpringConfig {
...
```

and put in src/test/resources/x/y/z/MyOneOffTest-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="widgetsService" class="com.mycompany.mydept.myservice.WidgetsService" primary="true" />

</beans>
```

That `widgetsService` bean will override (take the place of) the bean defined in the main config xml (or Java config). See about [inheritLocations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#inheritLocations--)
Also Note the default -context.xml file. Example of that [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles).
Update: I had to add `primary="true"`, apparently it's needed.

Answer (score -1):

Please see my answer in the other post for the right way to do bean overriding for tests. I think @Primary is a hack and may not even be usable if there is already a business use for it.

[Avoiding use of @MockBean to allow re-use of the spring-context via bean overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587213/using-mockbean-in-tests-forces-reloading-of-application-context/77857130#77857130)