# Spring boot 2.1 bean override vs. Primary

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With [Spring Boot 2.1 bean overriding is disabled](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes) by default, which is a good thing.

However I do have some tests where I replace beans with mocked instances using Mockito. With the default setting Tests with such a configuration will fail due to bean overriding.

The only way I found worked, was to enable bean overriding through application properties:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

However I would really like to ensure minimal bean definition setup for my test configuration, which would be pointed out by spring with the overriding disabled.

The beans that I am overriding are either

- Defined in another configuration that imported into my test configuration
- Auto-discovered bean by annotation scanning

What I was thinking should work in the test configuration overriding the bean and slap a `@Primary` on it, as we are used to for data source configurations. This however has no effect and got me wondering: Is the `@Primary` and the disabled bean overriding contradictory?

Some example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.foo;
@Service
public class AService {
}

package com.stackoverflow.foo;
public class BService {
}

package com.stackoverflow.foo;
@Configuration
public BaseConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public BService bService() {
        return new BService();
    }
}

package com.stackoverflow.bar;
@Configuration
@Import({BaseConfiguration.class})
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BService bService() {
        return Mockito.mock(BService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing your own configuration with a mock, why not use `@MockBean` and let Spring Boot do the replacement. So instead of `@Autowired BService bService` do `@MockBean BService bService` in your code. Saves you maintaining a configuration just for testing.

Comment: Comment from M. Deinum above does solve the case indeed, but only when you actually use mocks. When you need to override a bean in tests — it doesn't help.

Comment: Just a note, that using `@MockBean` in specific tests causes creating new context (instead of reusing cached one) and leads to slower tests run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overriding beans means that there may be only one bean with a unique name or id in the context. So you can provide two beans in the following way:

```
package com.stackoverflow.foo;
@Configuration
public class BaseConfiguration {
   @Bean
   @Lazy
   public BService bService1() {
       return new BService();
   }
}

package com.stackoverflow.bar;
@Configuration
@Import({BaseConfiguration.class})
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BService bService2() {
        return Mockito.mock(BService.class);
    }
}
```

If you add `@Primary` then primary bean will be injected by default in:

```
@Autowired
BService bService;
```

Comment: Hi, for me it also doesn't work. And what can you do, if `BaseConfiguration` is not public, but package private?

Answer (score 30):

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` can be placed in test configurations. If you need extensive integration testing, you will need to override beans at some point. It's inevitable.

Though the correct answer has already been provided, it implies that your bean will have different names. So, technically, it's not an override.

If you need a real override (because you use `@Qualifiers`, `@Resources` or something similar), since Spring Boot 2.X is only possible using the `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` property.

**Update:**
Be careful with Kotlin Bean Definition DSL. In Spring Boot it will require a custom ApplicationContextInitializer, like so:

```
class BeansInitializer : ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    override fun initialize(context: GenericApplicationContext) =
            beans.initialize(context)

}
```

Now if you decide to override one of such DSL-based beans in your test via `@Primary @Bean` method, it will not do. The initializer will kick in after `@Bean` methods and you'd still get the initial, DSL-based bean in your tests even with `@Primary` on the test `@Bean`.
One other option would be to also create a test initializer for your tests and list them all in your test properties, like so(order matters):

```
context:
    initializer:
        classes: com.yuranos.BeansInitializer, com.yuranos.TestBeansInitializer
```

Bean Definition DSL also supports primary property via:

```
bean(isPrimary=true) {...}
```

- which you'll need to eliminate ambiguity when you try to inject a bean, **however `main:allow-bean-definition-overriding: true` is not needed if you go pure DSL way.**

(Spring Boot 2.1.3)

Comment: I don't know why but even with `allow-bean-definition-overriding` my test bean has no precedence over default one. Because of it I will use `@MockBean(..)`

Answer (score 12):

I make the testing beans available only in `test` profile, and allow overriding for just while testing, like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
class FooBarApplicationTests {

  @Test
  void contextLoads() {}
}
```

The bean I am mocking in the test configuration:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class FooBarApplicationTestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public SomeBean someBean() {
    return Mockito.mock(SomeBean.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to override @Component with @Bean by default. In your case

```
@Service
public class AService {
}

@Component
public class BService {
    @Autowired
    public BService() { ... }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public BaseConfiguration {
}

@Configuration
// WARNING! Doesn't work with @SpringBootTest annotation
@Import({BaseConfiguration.class})
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean // you allowed to override @Component with @Bean.
    public BService bService() {
        return Mockito.mock(BService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still need to apply this property: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` as well as `@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, TestConfiguration.class})` to make it work.

Comment: Defining the TestConfiguration class in `@SpringBootTest` finally did the trick for me. Thanks Duc Tran