# Overriding spring @Configuration in an integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a spring boot configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ClockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Clock getSystemClock() {
        return Clock.systemUTC();
    }
}
```

and I have some integration tests like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest  {

}
```

and tests like this:

```
public class MiscTests extends AbstractIntegrationTest{

    @Test
    public void CreateSomethingThatOnlyWorksInThe Morning_ExpectCorrectResponse() {

    }
```

I want to be able to offset the clock bean to run some tests at different times on the day.  How do I do this?

NOTE:  I see [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139244/spring-boot-2-1-bean-override-vs-primary/55472911#55472911) [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742920/overriding-beans-in-integration-tests) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041542/override-a-single-configuration-class-on-every-spring-boot-test) similar to this, but I can't get them to work.

Based on other responses, it appears the solution should be something like:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest  {

    @Configuration
    class MyTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public Clock getSystemClock() {
            Clock realClock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
            return Clock.offset(realClock, Duration.ofHours(9));
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing happens there.  Do I need to @Import something?  do I need to @Autowired something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Spring Boot you can take advantage of the `@MockBean` annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest  {

    @MockBean
    private Clock clockMock;
}
```

Then you can stub public methods of that bean an each of the tests accordingly and uniquely:

```
@Test
public void CreateSomethingThatOnlyWorksInThe Morning_ExpectCorrectResponse() {
     when(clockMock.getTime()).thenReturn(..);
}
```

As per javadoc of `@MockBean`:

> Any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will
>   be replaced by the mock.

Comment: hmm, I'm confused.  When you say: 
{at}MockBean
    private Clock clockMock;
    
    did you mean:  
{at}MockBean
    public ClockConfiguration mockClock;    

keeping in mind, the class I want to override (or mock) is called "ClockConfiguration".  Anyhow, when I add what I think you meant, I get this error:  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Comment: @user952342 you cant overtide configuration with mock framework. To override configuration you need Testconfiguration . If you use Mock you need to Mock the Clock, not the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

it is the  @TestConfiguration annotation that you need https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ClockServiceImplIntegrationTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestOverridingClockServiceConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public ClockService clockService() {
            return new ClockServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private ClockService clockService;

    @MockBean
    private ClockRepository clockRepository;

    // write test cases here
}
```

In the case you have existing configuration you c