# Accessing @LocalServerPort in Configuration Class while running Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm running a full SpringBoot Application using a random port in my `SpringBootTest`.
I can retrieve the random port in my test class by using the annotation `@LocalServerPort`:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTest.LocalConfig.class})
public class MyTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private Integer port;
```

Unfortunately I cannot retrieve the random port in my `Configuration` class, where I want to create test beans using the random port:

```
  @TestConfiguration
  public static class LocalConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(@Value("${local.server.port}") int port) {
```

Here I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [knoobie](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14877#issuecomment-603873031) I've figured out this solution:

```
@Lazy
@TestConfiguration
public static class LocalConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean(@Value("${local.server.port}") int port) {
```

If you use `@Lazy`, you can access the value `local.server.port` in the `Configuration` class.

The Beans in the Lazy Configuration class will be instantiated at last, so the port is available in that phase.

Unfortunately it is not possible to use the `@Primary` annotation in combination with `@Lazy` for [overriding beans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746352/1909531), because `@Primary` annotated beans are instantiated at an early phase.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer for me is from Baeldung:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-running-port#1-using-servletwebserverapplicationcontext

```
@Autowired
private ServletWebServerApplicationContext webServerAppCtxt;

@Test
public void given0AsServerPort_whenReadWebAppCtxt_thenGetThePort() {
    int port = webServerAppCtxt.getWebServer().getPort();
 
    assertTrue(port > 1023);
}
```