# Spring MVC - Override a bean for one Integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project with spring MVC v5.0.8, Java 8
I've made some integration test from controller to database, and now, I want to add one which will test what happens if the first part of a transactional behavior failed. I'll ensure that the transaction is effectively roll-backed.
So, I've to override a DAO to make it fail. After some research, came up a simple idea : override spring config for that test : [Overriding an Autowired Bean in Unit Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866949/10273786)
My test work fine now, but the problem is that this configuration is shared with other test from other classes, even if it is in one class. How can I make it specific to that test ?

(If b creation fail, a must be roll-backed)
Failing test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@Sql({"/sqlfiles/clean-data.sql"})
public class AControllerFailDaoIt {

    @Configuration
    static class ConfigFailDao extends ApplicationConfiguration{
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public BDao getBDao() {
            return new BDao() {
                //Overriding method to make it fail
            };
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    AController aController;

    @Autowired
    ADao aDao;

    @Test
    public void should_not_create_a_if_b_failed(){
        //creation of a

        //assert nor a nor b are created
    }
}
```

Nominal test case :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfiguration.class, CustomWebAppConfiguration.class})
@Sql({"/sqlfiles/clean-data.sql"}) //"/sqlfiles/account-test.sql"
public class AControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    AController aController;

    @Autowired
    ADao aDao;

    @Autowired
    BDao bDao;

    @Test
    public void should_create_a_and_corresponding_b(){
        //create a
        //assert that both a and b are created
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfiguration (which is test-specific)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.base.package")
class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
}
```

Note : my Integration test classes are within the base package, does it matters ?
I found an option : put the fail test config in an external class, and call it only on my fail test, but it still doesn't work.
At the moment, I ran out of ideas, so I'll welcome your help !

Comment: If you are specifying the configuration only in this test class @ContextConfiguration annotation then I don't think it will be share with other test classes?

Comment: I will suggest rather than overriding dao execute test with specific data that throws some exception or use mocking to throw some exception on second step.

Comment: Thanks for your time !
If I make two separate configuration, let's say ApplicationConfiguration for regular test, and ApplicationConfigurationFail for this one, they all get the fail config (probably because of the @Primary as Guts stated), even If I call  
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfiguration.class, CustomWebAppConfiguration.class})  
for the regular test.

Comment: I'm trying to figure a way to make specific data to throws some exception, but the only way if to get an already existing ID, but since they are generated via UUID.randomUUID() in the Dao, I don't know what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. In a bad way, so if you have a better option, I'm in. But I didn't found a way to make my test fail by data... Which would be the better one.
So, I've found that the @Configuration annotation make a class scanned. [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).
I just made my fail configuration in an outer class, and remove the @Configuration annotation. So it won't be scanned by other test configuration. Then in my fail test class, I referenced it in the @ContextConfiguration annotation, so it is used. This way it work fine. I now have a problem with @Transactional, but that's not this thread.
Thanks to responders, you made me look in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use @Qualifier annotation.

1. Instead of putting @Primary above getBDao() method in your configuration put @Qualifier with some name i.e.:

   ```
   @Bean
   @Qualifier("BDaoTest")
   public BDao getBDao() {
       return new BDao() {
           //Overriding method to make it fail
       };
   }
   ```
2. After that put @Primary on your default BDao implementation (in your default config).
3. Then when you autowire this bean in your test you need to put this qualifier:

   ```
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("BDaoTest")
   BDao bDao;
   ```

Comment: The problem is that the controller autowire a service class, that autowire the BDao, and that's this autowired instance that I need to replace on my test.
Actually, hey are autowired in my test class to query the database, but technically I don't need the BDao in the fail test, so I'm removing it.